# error: cannot find symbol class GoogleAccountCredential

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-play-services, build.gradle, google-api-java-client

By Android build is failing with following error -

```
Error:(23, 68) error: package com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth does not exist
Error:(60, 20) error: cannot find symbol class GoogleAccountCredential
Error:(79, 19) error: cannot find symbol class GoogleAccountCredential
Error:(218, 22) error: cannot find symbol variable GoogleAccountCredential
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

I am not able to figure out what library this class belongs to. Package is

> com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.authc.GoogleAccountCredential;

I have tried adding all libraries in the build dependency. It looks like below now -

```
dependencies {

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:9.0.2'

compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'


compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'

// V2: Endpoints Framework v2 migration
endpointsServer project(path: ':DeviceLocatorBackend', configuration: 'endpoints')
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:+'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.22.0'
}
```

Comment: play services version 9.0.2? Any reason why you don't use the latest version?

Comment: I think I need to add repository source. I could not fetch latest versions. But that's not my problem right now. I am ok with old versions of libraries as long as nothing breaks.

Comment: it should be part of google-api-client lib and that you have added. Do you have included mavenCentral()?

Comment: No I have `jcenter()` but the dependency is getting resolved correctly.

Comment: Hm.. you have added the dependency again below: `compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:+'` this line shouldn't be necessary as you have added it before already. However this probably won't fix your problem..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Had to add following dependency to make it work -

```
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0'
```